# UITableView subview appearing over cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I added a subview to my UITableView, and gave it `sendsubviewtoback:` on that subview. The problem is, it's still overlapping my cell content.

Is this a known problem, and is there a workaround for this?

I need the subview to scroll with the UITableView, as you might imagine.

Comment: It's actcually hard to imagine what are you trying to do... Is this subView added to `tablveView`'s `view` or to it's `superView`? A screenshot would help. Also some code where you hide/show this `subView`.

Comment: check if you can accomplish whatever you try by using either `tableView.tableHeaderView`, `tableView.tableFooterView`, `- tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`, or `- tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`. It's usually not a good idea to add subviews directly to nontrivial built-in views and controls

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I think i'll have to go back to that. It's just an overlaying view with a top, a middle, and a bottom, so it made more sense (and made the app go faster) to have it be 1 subview covering the whole thing. it's added to the tableView's view.

Comment: Are you set a view as background to your tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line :

```
[tableName setBackgroundView:view];
```

Surely solve your problem.